# Power App Form and Sharepoint List - Getting Correct Date in Form but not correct time

Tags: powerapps-canvas

I have two Power App Canvas forms.

One is a Submit Request Form, the other is Staff View Edit Request Form. The Request Form submits the information to a SharePoint List. The field I am having an issue with is the Date Time Field in the Edit form, which pulls the info from the request submitted to the Sharepoint list. It is set to Date and Time and shows correctly in the Sharepoint list.

[image: this image is what it looks like in the Sharepoint list]

When the Staff view the Edit Form, the date is correct, but the time only displays 12:00 AM.
[image: This is how it is displayed in the Edit Form]

I have looked for and tried several solutions for a few days and cannot find one. Anyone have any ideas on how to make this work?

I have looked for and tried several solutions for a few days and cannot find one.